# find free space in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using MyISAM

Simply How to find table's free space in single **schema**?

Comment: What do you mean by free space?

Comment: database free space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myself found an answer in google

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB", sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
```

[To get the current database size](http://mysqladministrators.blogspot.in/2012/02/get-database-size.html)

Comment: That's the complete opposite of the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The data_free for MyISAM table is always 0

[information_schema.TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)

> The DATA_FREE column shows the free space in bytes for ***InnoDB*** tables.